# HttpRequest xhr Post using form vaiables

Tags: ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

So I must be over looking something very basic.  I am trying to send form data to update mysql records using an ajax http post request.  I have a page with a form.  On the form i have a submit button that calls the http request from a seperate js file and that js file calls a php file.  Using firebug, it doesn't look like i have any errors but when i "print" the sql that the request returns it is not passing the actual variables it is just passing "$_POST['name']" literallty.

It ruturns the sql:

```
UPDATE contacts SET name= "$_POST['name']" , phone = "$_POST['phone']" WHERE id = "$_POST['id']"
```

instead of passing in the actual variable values. My question is how do i pass in the actual varialbe data so that it returns somethign like:

```
UPDATE contacts SET name= "Mike", phone = "303-333-3333" WHERE id = "001"
```

My form (which doesn't contain form tags around it) looks like this:

```
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
    </label> 
    <label>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input  onclick="sendData()"type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
    </label>
```

my js in a seperate file looks like:

```
    function sendData()
 {

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
     document.getElementById("center").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","xhr_php/send.php",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send("name={$_POST['name']}&phone={$_POST['phone']}&id={$_POST['id']} ");
 }
```

my send.php file looks like:

```
db_connection include

$name= $_POST['name'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

print $query = "UPDATE contacts SET 
        name = '{$name}',
        phone = '{$phone}', 
WHERE id= {$id}";

$results= mysql_query($query, $db_connection);
if(mysql_affected_rows()==1){
    echo "Success";
}
if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
    echo "failed";
}
```

Again everything seems to work correctly in terms of calling the right files, it is just not passing any variable data.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the mistake is on the line

```
xmlhttp.send("name={$_POST['name']}&phone={$_POST['phone']}&id={$_POST['id']} ");
```

Change it to something like this:

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
xmlhttp.send("name="+name+"&phone="+phone+"&id="+id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That did the trick, I knew it was something simple.  Thanks!